# How to extract out several projects into one project using iframes

Tags: node.js, angular, express, iframe

In my company there are 3 independent projects written in angular. The customer has asked the company for the following:
create a project which will enable the user to connect to each one of the independent projects.My question is a general question - is iframe the correct technology for this usecase - and what do I need to know when I use iframes for that use case.

Comment: Do you have control over where the 3 independent sites are deployed?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't simply link to each project? Does the client require everything to be hiding behind their URL? If so, why not have sub-domains of theirs (assuming they own their domain) point to each of the three projects?

Comment: Will, In my case it is about the user of the 'main app' being able to choose between the projects, also connect,  maintain the state of each one of the projects, in a part of multisession node backend where the user connect to other users of different apps. If as you suggest, a link will be enough, how will the main app manage the small ap state? any idea?

Answer (score 1):

This is what we do, the iframe communicates with the apps and gives the token (it is called on init of each app) then you can provide some type of menu (or app picker) inside the header component where the use can choose any app. Keep in mind that the cookies/ls are saved on browser so presumably if the user hasnt logged out and your authentication is setup correctly they should be able to switch between apps just by switching URL's

Comment: Michael. Why is token needed? Do you mean when the user of the main app is logged in, a token should be sent to each one of the apps? Also - how would the main app manage the redux state of each one of the iframe-connected apps?